# how to set BaseImage, Small Image, Thumbnail to different images for each product in database

Tags: magento-1.7, catalog, image

I have imported a number of products at once, but the problem is: the Base Image, Small Image, Thumbnail are all set to the same image.

On the catalog page, I'm trying to change the image shown when you hover over a product. I believe, to do this, the small image and thumbnail image would need to be set to different images for the same product.

How can I achieve this?

I found below query, but I do not understand how to modify it to meet my requirement.

```
UPDATE
    catalog_product_entity_media_gallery AS mg,
    catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value AS mgv,
    catalog_product_entity_varchar AS ev
SET
    ev.value = mg.value
WHERE
    mg.value_id = mgv.value_id
AND
    mg.entity_id = ev.entity_id
AND
    ev.attribute_id IN (70, 71, 72)
AND
    mgv.position = 1;
```

Please, can you help me find the right modifications.

Comment: anyone please..?

Comment: Golden rule of Magento: Don't touch Magento DB directly. If you want I can give you solution how programmatically change media images

Comment: @mageUz PLease provide me a solution for my above problem? I need to change the product image on hover on the catalog page

Comment: For some reason this is not working for me even if I checked the attribute_id:s from database and made corrections. It only set the images for 3 products. All the rest of the hundreds of products remain unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

Here is given programmatically adding media images to product, you can adjust this code to your own importing script:

```
    $mediaGalleryAttribute = Mage::getModel('catalog/resource_eav_attribute')
        ->loadByCode(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY, 'media_gallery');
    $mediaGallery          = $mediaGalleryAttribute->getBackend();
    $attrCode              = $mediaGalleryAttribute->getAttributeCode();


    $product          = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
    $mediaGalleryData = $product->getData($attrCode);
    /**
     * If you want to remove old images use this code
     */
    if (isset($mediaGalleryData['images'])) {
        foreach ($mediaGalleryData['images'] as &$image) {
            $image['removed'] = 1;
        }
        $product->setData($attrCode, $mediaGalleryData);
    }
    /**
     * Here is real image file path
     */
    $thumbnailFile = 'real/path/to/thumbnail/file.jpg';
    $imageFile     = 'real/path/to/image/file.jpg';
    try {
        //Set thumbnail
        $imageFileUri = $mediaGallery->addImage($product, $thumbnailFile, null, false, false);
        $mediaGallery->setMediaAttribute($product, 'thumbnail', $imageFileUri);

        //Set image (or base image, small image whatever you want
        $imageFileUri = $mediaGallery->addImage($product, $imageFile, null, false, false);
        $mediaGallery->setMediaAttribute($product, 'image', $imageFileUri);
        $product->save();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        Mage::logException($e);
    }
```

Comment: Perfect, did exactly what I need to do. Thanks a lot:)

Answer (score 0):

May my solution works for you:

1. I would introduce an attribute (image) called for example "hover_image"
2. Use this function from Marius to set for example every second media-image as your hover-image
   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19153891/magento-how-to-programatically-set-the-base-image-to-the-first-image-in-the-lis Take care - you have to modify it to use the second image.